# Migrator.net drop table in Up(), what to do in Down()?

Tags: data-migration, migratordotnet

I have [Migrator.net](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) implemented in my project and I am removing a table from the current schema. My `Up()` simply contains `Database.RemoveTable("FooTable")`. But now I'm at a bit of a loss as to what I'm supposed to do for my `Down()`. Do I need to manually parse all past migrations for modifications on `FooTable`? Is there a way to run all previous migrations on FooTable in `Down()`?

Comment: I've taken up a habit of simply examining the current structure of whatever I am dropping and simply recreating it in the `Down()` as opposed to checking all previous migrations by hand. I'd still be interested in seeing if anyone has a more elegant solution to this though. Perhaps I should start looking to patch Migrator.net itself?

Comment: That's what I'd do as well. I have not thought about it (haven't been there yet), but it seems logical that when you're dropping the table, the opposite action is creating it. Checking all previous migrations by hand sounds terrible. Too much work and too much error prone.

Answer (score 3):

What about the data? If there were 50,000 rows, recreating an empty table doesn't rollback to the previous state.

To enable database downgrades with data you need to:

1. In Up(), detach the table from your data model (e.g. drop FKs) and rename it to something like DeleteMe_FooTable. Do not actually drop it however.
2. In Down(), reattach it to your data model - rename it to its original name and restore FKs.
3. A few days/weeks after the deployment, when you know you are 100% guaranteed never to rollback, a DBA can manually delete the table.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of `Down()` is that it would reverse the effects of you `Up()` method, so technically if you ran `Up()` and then `Down()` right after your database schema would be back where you started.

in your case you would have to recreate the Table in your `Down()`

Comment: Please read my comment to the question. I know I have to re-create the table in the `Down()`. I was more looking for an elegant solution than analyzing the current schema for the table and re-creating it by hand.